# NSArray count not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

So I have a `UITableView`, and I populate the tableview with data from a `.plist`.  This has been working fine for me until today, when I tried to do the same and I can't get the `numberOfRowsInSection`, method to work. Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if...

     else if (segmentOptions == exchange){
         NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[exchangeDictionary objectForKey:[listOfExchanges objectAtIndex:section]]];
         return [array count];
     }   

   //Else
    return contentArray.count;
}
```

So in that code, everytime I run it, the code crashs.  But, I use basiacally the same code to set the tableview text and that works fine:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     }

     if...

     else if (segmentOptions == exchange) {
           NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[exchangeDictionary objectForKey:[listOfExchanges objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
           cell.textLabel.text =  [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

     return cell;
}
```

And that code works fine, which is why I'm so confused.  When I set the number of rows to return to a specific number, and run the rest of the code, everything works fine.  So I'm really lost.  Thands in advance

**UPDATE**
I tried it with the proper `count` notation, `return [array count];`, and I still get the same crash and the same console output.

Comment: What do you get when it crashes?

Comment: In order to provide you with a solution, we need to see a crash report, or at least more information regarding the crash.

Comment: This is the only thing that comes up in the console: `warning: Frame pointer point back at the previous frame
(gdb) `  -  but i didnt think that was useful

Comment: Quote the EXACT message.  And how do you know it's "crashed"?

Comment: (I suspect that your "array" is coming back nil.)

Comment: That is the exact message.  Literally that is all that is shown in the console.

Answer (score 5):

First, count is not a property so you should not be using dot syntax to access it.

I would suggest changing your code so that you are not accessing the count method like a property.

Second,

Test to see if your array is nil and that it is even an array.

Third,

Post the actual complete stack trace.

Comment: It's fairly common to access `count` using property notation.  It works, and the compiler never complains.

Comment: (In fact, the only functional difference between `[array count]` and `array.count` is that the former will return zero if `array` is nil while the latter will take a storage exception.)

Comment: @HotLicks, both [array count] and array.count will return zero if array is nil. They're both the same code. People disagree on which is proper style of course.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I'll have to try it again, but my prior experience was that the dot notation resulted in a storage error.

Comment: Dot syntax doesn't really change the generated code, it's just syntactic sugar. So someObj.someProp generates the same code as [someObj someProp], with no difference in behavior regardless of what someObj is.

Comment: It is not "fairly common ..."; it is wrong. It is against the intention of dot syntax.  Eliminating every issue in the code helps to narrow down the problem.  Dot syntax should not be used for non-properties.  It is that simple.

Comment: Conceptually, `-count` is a read-only property of an `NSArray`, so you could argue that it's ok to use dot-syntax. </devil's advocate>

Comment: @NickForge Nope, it is not a property; end of story.  If people want to use it like that they should file a radar for count to be turned into a property.

Comment: If it isn't a property (and it clearly isn't), then why does dot syntax work!? I quickly checked if i'm doing this in my project. Turns out i'm using JSON Framework in my current project and it's using dot syntax to access count of NSMutableArray :)

Comment: Marcus, can you explain more why it is wrong to use the dot notation for calling non-property methods? I kinda agree with this rule based on the "rigour enforcement," but I'm wondering if there is a technical reason.

Comment: No technical reason really but it is a mental overhead. Chris Hanson has a good [blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=160) on it. Use dot notation/properties for state exposed by your objects and bracketed syntax to invoke behaviours. It is more about the mental overhead for the programmer than technical limitations. I am of course referring to state that is either backed by an ivar or calculated (count would make a good example if it was declared as such) not any random method you want to use with dot syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure that the comment from Marcus on dot notation is relevant here; it's certainly not "wrong". Dot-notation and properties are orthogonal concepts and whilst they usually go hand in hand, I see no reason not use them for conceptual properties in older APIs that pre-date `@property`. The underlying implementation just isn't be relevant. If it's a conceptual property with no side-effects, then feel free to use dot-notation if that's your preferred style (as it is mine).

Comment: @LukeRedpath - I think the point he's trying to make here is that this isn't really an accessor method, so it's a little awkward to use dot notation for this.  Chris Hanson argues that -`-count` is an attribute: https://twitter.com/eschaton/status/138863954121330688 , but I've never felt comfortable using dot syntax for it.  I think of it more like a computation than a strict accessor, as Paul indicates. I'm fine with using dot syntax for non-`@property` accessors, but something about this rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: Marcus, what I posted is literally all the console displayed.  There is **nothing** else being printed.  I don't know what else you would like?  - Second, I did test if the array is nil, and I am SURE it is not.  I manually logged it in that method and it is also working properly in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method.  - third, even if dot notation is technically incorrect, I have used it many times before without trouble, so I doubt that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Break it down and debug, if console message is not being helpful. It helps sometimes, specially when it's late. i.e.

```
// NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[exchangeDictionary objectForKey:[listOfExchanges objectAtIndex:section]]];

NSLog(@"%d", section);

id objAtIndex = [listOfExchanges objectAtIndex:section];
NSLog(@"%@", listOfExchanges);
NSLog(@"%@", objAtIndex);

id objForKey = [exchangeDictionary objectForKey:objAtIndex];
NSLog(@"%@", exchangeDictionary);
NSLog(@"%@", objForKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It has been the most helpful so far.  I tried it, and everything logged properly.  So I tried this: `int count = [[exchangeDictionary objectForKey:objForKey] count];
        NSLog(@"ct = %i", count);
` and I got `ct = 0` in the console.  That doesnt make sense to me because the array is logging propery, so I know its not nil, and yet its returning 0

Comment: This makes me remember the days of `retain` and `release`, and wonder if I tried to retain it, would it work?

Comment: If you're using ARC, don't do that! Have you tried debugging your code using NSZombieEnabled and/or using Instruments?

Comment: I was just kidding. haha.  I know I cant do that, I was just kinda making a joke about the old days. haha  but i do have NSZombieEnabled enabled and i dont think its helping.  and im not totally comforatable with instruments.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
[array count]
```

count is not a property, it is a method you run on the array.

Comment: Making that change will likely make the code stop crashing, but will not make it work.

Comment: Based off of this: "When I set the number of rows to return to a specific number, and run the rest of the code, everything works fine." I assume that his array is not nil since his app works when he inputs the return value manually, and that the only problem is the count causing the app to crash.

Comment: I think you read too much into that.  If `array` is not nil then `array.count` will work, so `array` being nil seems like the most likely problem.

Comment: I don't understand why his app would work when he manually returns a value. The array must contain data if it is being properly read in cellForRowAtIndexPath when he hard codes the return value of numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: Dot-notation and properties are orthogonal; it is perfectly valid to call methods like `count` using dot-notation. It's a conceptual property with no side-effects and `[array count]` and `array.count` are functionally identical.

Comment: I am fairly sure I understand what I'm doing with this.  I understand what I was trying to do, and have do it successfully a million times.  The reason why I posted this question is because I was having trouble and couldn't figure it out  by myself.

Comment: As Luke said, they are the same and I knew that before I posted the question.  I tried both `array.count` and `[array count]` and both don't work.